# Problem 4, Section 3.8 Kreyszig.

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be an inner product space and we consider the map $$T\colon X\longrightarrow X'\;\text{defined as}\quad z\longmapsto \langle \cdot, z \rangle_X.$$

We suppose that the above map is surjective, then I must prove that $X$ must be an Hilbert space.

**My Attempt**

The map $T$ is injective: $$T(z)=T(v)\implies T(z)(x)=T(v)(x)\quad\forall x\in X\implies \langle x, z\rangle=\langle x,v\rangle\quad\forall x\in X\\ \implies \langle x,z-v\rangle=0\quad\forall x\in X \\\implies \langle z-v, z-v\rangle=0\\\implies z=v$$

$T$ is an isometry: $$\lVert T(z)\rVert=\lVert\langle \cdot,z \rangle_X\lVert\color{red}=\rVert z\lVert$$ where the red equality is a simply exercise.

Therefore $T$ is a bijective isometry and so $X$ and $X'$ are isometric. Since $X'$ is a Banach space it's complete respect to the metric induced by the norm $\lVert\cdot \rVert_{X'}$ on $X'$, then also $X$ is complete respect to the metric induced by the inner product, and so $X$ is an Hilbert space.

It's correct?

Comment: Yes. Just about terminology - an isometry of normed spaces is usually assumed to be a linear map. Your map is not linear, but it doesn't matter. What matters is that it preserves distances and bijective, and so $X$ and its dual are isomorphic as metric spaces.

Comment: @Mark Thanks!$d_{X'}(T(z), T(v))=\lVert T(z)-T(x)\rVert _{X'}=\lVert T(z-v) \rVert=\lVert z-v \lVert =d_X(z,v)$. It's correct? Even if the map is conjugate linear, when the coefficients are real as in this case, can I write what I wrote?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. It is linear with respect to real scalars, and $(-1)$ is real.